# why MYSQL HEX function is acting strangely?

Tags: mysql, hex

the output of **select hex(user())** is **726F6F74406C6F63616C686F7374**
and **select unhex('726F6F74406C6F63616C686F7374')** will produce **root@localhost**.

but in case **select('select * from accounts')** which will give **73656C656374202A2066726F6D20746573742E6163636F756E7473**, the below query is not executed and just print the corresponding string!!!!!!!!

**Query:** **select unhex('73656C656374202A2066726F6D20746573742E6163636F756E7473')**

**Output: select * from accounts**

Comment: Did you try removing the '' from the query?  You're just passing in a string.

Comment: yes, I did it, but got error. it seems using quotation for long strings is required

Comment: have you tried () instead?  I'm sorry I can't be of more assistance

Comment: Using parentheses will make inside query to be executed and then HEX of the result will be calculated.

Comment: I just assumed that thats what you were trying to do

Comment: *using quotation for long strings is require* has nothing to do with it, and also not the hex-function itself. If you do "select <something>" or "hex(<something>)", <something> has to evaluate to a single value. If it is the (one) hex of a  user, that's fine. If it is a (long, but still just one) string, that's fine too. If it is the content of a table (with more than one column) that's not fine. (That is what the error message that you should get (and that you should add to your question) means). Please explain what you are trying to do, so we can maybe point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is a Time-Based Blind SQL injection scenario which you cannot use comma in your queries because it is interpreted as delimiter in back-end code. For example if you inject SELECT LEFT(USER(),1); what will be get to database is SELECT LEFT(USER() 1); which has syntax error. SO I'm looking for a solution to use queries without the need of COMMA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of execution of commands in the database is as follows:

unhex(hex(user())

unhex(hex(database())

unhex(hex(group_concat+table_name())

First,the database evaluates the user() function :

root@localhost

and then hexadecimal value will be calculated:

726F6F74406C6F63616C686F7374

Then unhex() returns the value of 726F6F74406C6F63616C686F7374:

root@localhost

So the final output will be the following value : root@localhost

These methods were previously used for bypass Web Application Firewalls.